# Regex - Extract date from file name in list of files

Tags: regex, date, filenames

I have multiple files on a local directory named like this:

```
asd-3A-yyyyMMdd
```

Where yyyyMMdd represents a date.
There are also files named:

```
bcd-3A-yyyyMMdd
```

And a bunch of files with different names, unnecesary to me.
How can I extract only the date from the files starting with **asd**?
Nothing I tried seems to work.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? We can maybe go from there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Solution

This regex

```
asd-[0-9][a-z]-([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})
```

[image]

Will do the following

- require the string to

  - start with the characters `asd-`
  - followed by a number a letter, and a `-`
  - followed by numbers resembling a date.
- creates the following capture groups

  - 0 the entire matched string
  - 1 the year
  - 2 the month
  - 3 the day

**Note**: This regex does not validate the date is legitimate.

## Example

See also [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SEvxrJ/1)

Given the following sample text

```
bsd-3A-20170523
asd-3A-20170523
NotTheDroidsYourLookingFor-20171131
asd-1D-20170523
```

Returns the following matches

```
Match 1
Full match  16-31   `asd-3A-20170523`
Group 1.    23-27   `2017`
Group 2.    27-29   `05`
Group 3.    29-31   `23`

Match 2
Full match  68-83   `asd-1D-20170523`
Group 1.    75-79   `2017`
Group 2.    79-81   `05`
Group 3.    81-83   `23`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  asd-                     'asd-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-z]                    any character of: 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{4}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
```